# Поменять описание привилегии по уменьшению рекламы в настройках профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, реклама

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: настройки отображения рекламы]

Это и с толку сбивает, и противоречит даже названию привилегии [на странице привилегии "Меньше рекламы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).

> Из уважения к нашим постоянным пользователям, по достижению ими необходимого уровня репутации мы автоматически **отключаем некоторые объявления**

Реклама не убирается полностью, лишь часть баннеров пропадает.

Comment: Но ты же всё равно _не хочешь_ видеть, но твои желания удовлетворяют лишь частично.

Comment: @Qwertiy в оригинале там "Do not show me **more** advertisements". Что лучше перевести как "Не хочу видеть дополнительную рекламу".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил на:

- [**Не показывать** мне дополнительную рекламу.](https://ru.traducir.win/string/1866)
- [Показывать мне дополнительную рекламу.](https://ru.traducir.win/string/568)